# How save a list of users to database using java 8 streams

Tags: java, stream

I want to be able to send a list of users, loop through each user and if user doesn't exist in database save it and if it exists throw an error.

I have this code so far:

```
public List<User> addUsers(@RequestBody List<User> userList) {
        return userRepository.saveAll(userList);
    }
```

And I would like to apply Java Streams

So far I came to this:

```
 public List<User> addUsers(@RequestBody List<User> userList) {
        userList.stream(
                .filter(user -> userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail()).isPresent(new ResourceAlreadyExistsException("User with", " email s% already exists", user.getEmail())))

        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return userRepository.saveAll(userList);
    }
```

It's not working. I am not sure how to do it with streams.
Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your code snippet has compilation errors. But there are conceptual problems as well:

- `Stream.collect(...)` produces a new list, so in your code snippet you are saving the unmodified userList.
- If you want to throw an exception in case of a `User` that already exists it will not provide you with the result you expect since it will stop at the first `User` that exists and not go any further. You would have to either change the method to only accept one `User` at a time, or modify the return type to something that can indicate whether a `User` was saved or not.

A correct way to only save and return non-existing `User` objects would be for example:

```
public List<User> addUsers(@RequestBody List<User> userList) {
    return userRepository.saveAll(userList.stream()
            .filter(user -> !userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail()).isPresent())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Here you create a stream from `userList`, filter those that can not be found by their email (you could create an `existByEmail(...)` method in the `userRepository` for this) then you collect it into a `List` that is passed straight to the `saveAll(...)` method

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped a lot!

Comment: You are welcome! Check out some short tutorials about streams, they are not as difficult as they might seem :)

Comment: Yes, they do seem, when you just start :D but will keep going :)